# php + facebook. geting access token returns: Error validating verification code

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After a user is redirected to login dialog

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$appid&scope=&" .
"redirect_uri=$process_url";
```

where $process_uri is urlencoded url of form `https://my.domain.com/process.php?param1=value1&param2=value2`. After user returned to `https://my.domain.com/process.php` I do curl request to (have tried to use `file_get_contents` first):

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .
"$appid&redirect_uri=$current_url&client_secret=$secret" .
"&code={$_REQUEST['code']}";
```

I'm getting `{ "error": { "message": "Error validating verification code.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }`.

After googling I realized that the main reason that may cause the problem is wrong `redirect_uri` in curl request. The question is: what should be `redirect_uri` in curl request? `https://my.domain.com/`? Or `https://my.domain.com/process.php`? Or `https://my.domain.com/process.php?param1=value1&param2=value2`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the code parameter when you're submitting the current URL as the redirect_uri to the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token endpoint.

Comment: Well I believe the redirect_uri is used as a hash so it must be submitted in exactly the same form as you provided to the authorize endpoint. The user is redirected to this uri with an extra parameter, code, so it should be sufficient to just remove the code parameter from the current URL. Ensure the encoding is the same (including casing). From your example above it should be "https://my.domain.com/process.php?param1=value1&param2=value2" encoded